# How to dynamically remove json key in Karate?

Tags: karate

I am trying to remove some json key based on a conditon. Below didn't work

```
 * def body
 * if (condition == 'true') remove body.path1.path2.key
(or)
 * def body = (condition == 'true')? (remove  body.path1.path2.key):body
```

I am also not sure why below code is giving error

```
* def json = { a: 1,b:2 }
* def key = 'b'
* karate.remove('json', key)
```

Error:
*evaluation (js) failed: karate.remove('json', key), java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected path: b*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
* def json = { a: 1, b: 2 }
* def key = 'b'
* if (true) karate.remove('json', key)
* match json == { a: 1 }
```

So `remove` is a Karate keyword so it won't work when mixed with JS.

But the JS engine in 1.0 onwards will support the JS `delete` keyword. So you can do things like this now:

```
* def json = { a: 1, b: 2 }
* def key = 'b'
* if (true) delete json[key]
* match json == { a: 1 }
```